# Javascript code inside <BODY> runs *before* <SCRIPT>s in <HEAD> are fully loaded?

Tags: javascript, execution, head

When I use the minified version (`ext-all.js`) everything is fine but when I replace it with `ext-all-debug.js` (everything else intact), firebug reports all sorts of errors due to undefined values that I *know* are defined in either Ext or other js files that I load after Ext.

After some trial and error, I put `console.log()`s at the end of few js files and none shows up. I think using `ext-all-debug.js` somehow causes the js code in `<BODY></BODY>` to be executed *before* the scripts in the `<HEAD>` are fully loaded and this results in "undefined" errors because the code in the `<BODY>` references values that are supposed to be loaded beforehand.

right ?

```
<HEAD>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="ext/ext-base.js"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="ext/ext-all-debug.js"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="my_lib.js"></SCRIPT> <!-- defines myValue -->
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
console.log(myValue) // undefined
</SCRIPT>
</BODY>
```

here is `my_lib.js`

```
var myValue = 10;
console.log("my_lib.js loaded");
```

And

> my_lib.js loaded

does not show up in the console.

Comment: What are `ext-all.js` & `ext-all-debug.js` ?

Comment: Are you sure you have the file name correct? If the lib fails to load this would explain your error messages perfectly.

Comment: @gdoron they are ExtJS core files

Comment: @bart the error shows up because the `console.log(myValue)` is executed *before* the `my_lib.js` is loaded (or so I suppose). The error prevents the page from going any further (firebug blocks)

Comment: If execution of `my_lib.js` depends on `ext-all-debug.js` and the latter is not loaded correctly, your lib won't execute properly, leaving `myValue` undefined. So, again, are you sure the file name is correct?

Comment: I do not now what causes this behaviour but if you want to make sure that myValue is properly used then just reference it in an onLoad event handler for the body.

Comment: @Bart I understand the possibility but I don't see how the file names are of relevance to it :-? `ext-all-debug.js` is `ext-all-debug.js` and the other one is of my own. If you would explain what do you mean exactly ... and forgive my slow brain :D

Comment: Well, if the file is actually named `ext-all_debug.js`, for instance, it won't load...

Comment: Open firebug and go to net tab and see whether the actual script is getting dowloaded or not

Comment: @Bart The file names are correct

Comment: @Ajaybeni I checked with firebug and all files are loaded !!! This invalidates my theory I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

As long as scripts aren't marked defer or async or loaded dynamically, they will execute in the order that they are encountered in the HTML file.  That is part of the spec so it's guaranteed.

If you are seeing `myValue` as undefined after you think you've defined it in an earlier script, then there is some other problem.

Some possibilities are:

1. One of your scripts has an error that prevents full execution.
2. Your variable isn't getting defined in the global scope, but rather some sub-scope so it isn't available at the global scope when you try to use it.
3. Your variable is defined by the previous script, but not successfully initialized to have a value other than `undefined`.
4. Your scripts aren't being found by the browser (and thus not loading/executing).

If you can show us a working/non-working page that exhibits the problem, we can likely spot the issue quickly.  As it is now with no sample page that shows the issue, we can only speculate on possible causes.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Appears that (my) `ext-all-debug.js` is buggy. After inspecting it in PhpStorm, I found few syntactic errors and fixed them. Everything works fine now.

Comment: don't you need ext-base.js to run ext-all? or was that just in previous versions?