# If the async attribute is used to load non blocking <script>s in the <head> are they guaranteed to be loaded before body.readyState == 'loaded'

Tags: javascript, html

Without the **async** or **defer** attribute the loading of JavaScript blocks the browser and any scripts loaded in the **<head>** are always loaded before the dom is loaded and body.readyState == 'loaded'.

My question is specific to the use of the **async** attribute to allow a non blocking **<script>** in the **<head>**. Some browsers can then start rendering the DOM while the javascript is still being retrieved. I have found situations where at least Chrome definitely does render prior to the **async** JavaScript load in the **<head>** completing.

Are these **async** loaded scripts and as a result the **<head>** guaranteed to be loaded before body.readyState == 'loaded' and traditional dom ready javascript is executed?

I can confirm in waterfalls using Chrome, Firefox and IE11 that in practice in my test cases the onload processing always occurred after all the JavaScript had loaded, and immediately afterwards in some cases, giving the impression that in current browsers the **async** does not break the assumption that JavaScript has loaded before the body state changes.

This however is anecdotal evidence and what I am looking for is a standard reference or reference/reasoning regarding the browser architecture that gives comfort that for a large javascript loaded in the **<head>** with **async** and a small **<body>** I will not find situations where the **<body>** completes loading and has a state of loaded before the **<head>** due to the use of non blocking **async** script loads.

Comment: Do you mean the `async` or `defer` attributes?

Comment: The more general case of a blocking load of a script is discussed in other questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585979/are-external-scripts-in-the-head-of-an-html-document-guaranteed-to-execute-befor) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115182/javascript-code-inside-body-runs-before-scripts-in-head-are-fully-loaded). This question applies to the non blocking loading of scripts and the effect on when **body** changes state.

Comment: _I will not find situations where the <body> completes loading and has a state of loaded before the <head> due to the use of non blocking async script loads._ I think you absolutely __will__ find that; why wouldn't you? What would be the point of async loading if this couldn't happen? (Or am I misunderstanding the question?)

Comment: Yes, as you say it's an attribute. I'll update the terminology in the question.

Comment: @Mathletics well the "load" event typically waits until all assets are loaded, though it sure seems like "load" will always fire even when some images (or CSS or whatever) time out.

Comment: @Pointy are assets referenced in the `head` considered part of the `body` content for `readyState`?

Comment: @Mathletics well I'm personally not really sure; I've been trying to find a specification. The MDN page for the "load" event is notably (and surprisingly) useless.

Comment: @Pointy same here. inconclusive thus far.

Comment: Um, `body` does not have a `.readyState`? [`document` has.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState)

Comment: @Bergi I think you are on to something. I am using `var body = document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0]; if (body && body.readyState == 'loaded') { ... }` so it looks like the readyState is actually implemented by document only which would explain why the head appears to get loaded before the body changes state. I'm actually receiving the state of the document and not the body. I'll create this as an answer to my own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

readyState is actually implemented by document and as a result the **<body>** only has a readyState of 'loaded' when the complete document (Both the **<head>** and the **<body>**) have loaded. Using the **async** attribute to load JavaScript in the **<head>** is safe in that all JavaScript will have loaded before the **<body>**, or actually anything, appears to be 'loaded'.

When the **<body>** is asked for its readyState the request is being responded to by its parentNode which is the document. [Document implements readyState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState).

The code initiating the on-load processing was:

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0];
if (body && body.readyState == 'loaded')
    { ... }
```

So yes, it is guaranteed that even async JavaScript files will be fully loaded before any on-load processing that tests a **<body>**'s readyState receives 'loaded'.

It however, would be far clearer, just to ask the document for its readyState.

Many thanks to @Bergi for pointing out, in a comment to the question, that it is actually document that is implementing readyState and for locating the documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState

Answer (score 0):

There are many things to consider when you want to know wich part of your html will be rendered first.

- Size of the script being loaded
- Size of the rest of the document
- What tecniques the browser uses to optimize the loading of content

Some browsers use speculative parsing to continue loading even if it finds a blocking script. Depending if the speculative loading succeeds the browser will use the content already retreived instead of continuing rendering the requested document.

You can read more about speculative parsing in the [mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Optimizing_your_pages_for_speculative_parsing)

If for example you have a huge script, say a complete spa aplication using an async attribute, is very likely that your document will render before the loading of the script finishes but this does not mean a loaded event will be triggered.

The readyState of the body it will be changed to 'loaded' after all assets (scripts, styles, etc) are loaded. Read loaded as downloaded or failed (also includes timeout). Your page is also considered one of this assets so this event only happens if all this conditions are true. 
The head of your document is also part of your page and needs to be downloaded before the documents is declared as ready and the onload event is triggered.

On the other side javascript execution is a different matter. Using the async attribute only garantees that the browser will continue to parse the document and **execute** the script **after it has finished downloading** which could be in any moment. Your document might be already downloaded or not, that depends on the ammount of content remaining. Also there is a chance that there are already other scripts being executed wich will delay the execution of your script.

The defer attribute is not a standard and can not be used as a garantee either.

From the docs

> This Boolean attribute is set to indicate to a browser that the script is meant to be executed after the document has been parsed. Since this feature hasn't yet been implemented by all other major browsers, authors should not assume that the script’s execution will actually be deferred. The defer attribute shouldn't be used on scripts that don't have the src attribute. Since Gecko 1.9.2, the defer attribute is ignored on scripts that don't have the src attribute. However, in Gecko 1.9.1 even inline scripts are deferred if the defer attribute is set.

Finally you should note that the async attribute is not supported in all browsers and will have no effect if your page is being requested from an older browser.